# Problems with the constructor of a class when extending from another I can not use methods in the constructor

Tags: php, class, inheritance, constructor, php-7

i have two class, one(controller class) extend from another, then in the controller class, I define a variable "load" (in the construct), but when i extend from another class i can't invoke this variable from the constructor, any ideas? (Apologies for my bad english).

Class Controller:

```
<?php

class Controller {
    protected $load;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->load = new Loader();

        if($_GET && isset($_GET['action']))
        {
            $action = $_GET['action'];

            if(method_exists($this, $action))
                $this->$action();
            else
                die('Method not found.');

        } else {
            if(method_exists($this, 'index'))
                $this->index();
            else
                die('Index method not found.');
        }
    }
}
```

Class home ( Where does it extend):

```
<?php
class Home extends Controller
{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model("HomeModel");// this line doesn't work
    }

    public function index() {

        $articles = new HomeModel();
        $articles = $articles->getData();
        $nombres = ['jona', 'juan', 'jose'];
        $view = new Views('home/home', compact("nombres", "articles"));
    }

}
```

Loader Class:

```
<?php

class Loader
{

    function __construct() {

    }

    public function model($model) {
        require('./models/'.$model.'.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What error do you get?

Comment: @AlexHowansky It just does not work, it's like I've never declared that line

Comment: @AlexHowansky When i declared " $this->load->model("HomeModel");" in the construct, this doesn't work, but when i declared this in index function this work correctly

Comment: What does the Loader actually do? And how do you know that it doesn't work?

Comment: @MarkBaker the Loader only include a file, and this doesn't work because when i clared this in the index function the results are printed correctly, but when i declared this in __construct this give me  this error
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'HomeModel' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc\controllers\Home.php:11 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc\app\Controller.php(20): Home->index() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc\controllers\Home.php(5): Controller->__construct() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc\index.php(18): Home->__construct() #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc\controllers\Home.php on line 11

Comment: Please check the path of require() and directory structure. FYI, think about proper autoloading classes in your project.

Comment: @BenRoob the paths are correct, the problem is this line "$this->load->model("HomeModel");// this line doesn't work", but when I declared this in the construct this doesn't work, but when i declare this in the index function this work correctly, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The error "'HomeModel' not found" would lead me to believe that you are not requiring the file that contains the 'HomeModel' class in the 'Home' class file.

Comment: The Loader class do this, but when I declared this from `__construct()` this doesn't work, but when I decalred this from `ìndex()` function, this work correctly.